How to show this inequality about two independent random variables s.t. $E[Y]=0.$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables in $L^p(\Omega,P)$, where $(\Omega, P)$ is a probability space. And suppose $E[Y]=0.$ Then, I want to know how to show $$\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}|x+y|^p dP_X(x) dP_Y(y)\geqq 
\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}|x+y|dP_Y(y)\right)^p dP_X(x).$$
(This is the step of proving $\|X+Y\|_p\geqq \|X\|_p$ and I'm stuck with the inequality above.)
By Tonelli, $\displaystyle LHS=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}|x+y|^p dP_Y(y) dP_X(x)$ so if I could see $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R}|x+y|^p dP_Y(y) \geqq\left(\int_{\mathbb R}|x+y|dP_Y(y)\right)^p$, the inequality would be proved.
Maybe I have to use $0=E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ by independence of $X$ and $Y$.
Any idea ?
(Perhaps, $p\geqq 1$ is needed.)

$(\int_{\mathbb R}|x+y|dP_Y(y))^p \le \int_{\mathbb R}|x+y|^{p}dP_Y(y)$ by Hölder's inequality. Integrate both sided w.r.t. $P_X$ and then apply Tonelli's Theorem.
